# Convert String in to time shows unhandled exception

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I want to convert the following `String`: "1:13 PM" to time format.
I am getting the following error: `Unhandled exception:java.text.ParseException`.

Here is my code:

```
String str = "1:13 PM";
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss a");
DateFormat date = formatter.parse(str);
```

Comment: same problem after adding your code

Comment: which code? I didn't provide any.

Answer (score 7):

Remove the `ss`, Its indicate second and you are not giving  second in the String, So when the parser looking for the second value it cannot find the second giving you the exception.

```
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");
```

And also change the next line to

```
try {
        Date date = formatter.parse(str);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: same problem after adding your code

Comment: @SAK you have a codding error as mentioned by @Zealous  `DateFormat date = formatter.parse(str);` this line should be ` Date date=formatter.parse(str);`

Comment: try my edited answer @SAK

Comment: try `DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("h:mm a", Locale.UK); Date date = formatter.parse(str)`

Comment: First, you missed locale, second, "hh" is for "01", not "1"

Answer (score 0):

Answer is same as @Saif but formatter.parse(str) will not convert it to DateFormat object it will convert it in Date object.

```
        String str = "1:13 PM";
        DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");
        try{
            Date date = formatter.parse(str);
        }catch(ParseException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: same problem after adding your code

Comment: @SAK you have to handle ParseException which is thrown by formatter.parse() method. I have edited code.refer it. :-)

Comment: First, you missed locale, second, "hh" is for "01", not "1"

Comment: @SashaSalauyou check the output first.

Comment: @Zealous even if it works for you, locale is a must.